# How to understand the print in GDB？

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I have an assembly code,

```
.section .data
    value1:
        .int 1 
    value2:
        .short 2
    value3:
        .byte 3
.global _start   
 _start:      
        nop
        movl value1,%ecx
    movw value1,%bx
    movw value2,%bx
    movb value3,%cl
         movl $1, %eax  
        movl $0, %ebx  
        int $0x80
```

I use as and ld to get the executable binary file.
But in GDB, I cannot print the value2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKEBV.png)

Why? I'm confused.

I found the address is out of the data section.

Comment: Your code is in data, is that intentional?

Comment: Don't know if this is related (since you can print `value1`) but your 'variables' are not correctly aligned. i.e. an `int` at `...9B` and a `short`at `...9F`.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues ...

1. You should have `.section .text` *before* `.global _start` so that `_start` ends up in the `.text` section
2. Add `-g` to get debug infomation

Unfortunately, adding `-g` to a `.c` compilation would be fine. But, it doesn't work too well for a `.s` file

Here's a simple C program, similar to yours:

```
int value1;
short value2;
unsigned char value3;
```

We can compile this with `-S` to get a `.s` file. We can do this with and without `-g`. Without `-g` the `.s` file is 7 lines. Adding `-g` increases this to 150 lines.

The debug information has to be added with special asm directives (e.g. `.loc` and `.section    .debug_info,"",@progbits`).

Then, `gdb` has enough information to allow `p` (or `x`) to work.

---

To get `p` to work *without* debug information, we have to *cast* the values to the correct type. For example, in your program:

```
p (int) value1
p (short) value2
p (char) value3
```

---

Here is the `.s` output for the sample `.c` file *without* `-g`:

```
    .file   "short.c"
    .text
    .comm   value1,4,4
    .comm   value2,2,2
    .comm   value3,1,1
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

---

Here is the `.s` output *with* `-g`:

```
    .file   "short.c"
    .text
.Ltext0:
    .comm   value1,4,4
    .comm   value2,2,2
    .comm   value3,1,1
.Letext0:
    .file 1 "short.c"
    .section    .debug_info,"",@progbits
.Ldebug_info0:
    .long   0x71
    .value  0x4
    .long   .Ldebug_abbrev0
    .byte   0x8
    .uleb128 0x1
    .long   .LASF5
    .byte   0xc
    .long   .LASF6
    .long   .LASF7
    .long   .Ldebug_line0
    .uleb128 0x2
    .long   .LASF0
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x5
    .long   0x33
    .uleb128 0x9
    .byte   0x3
    .quad   value1
    .uleb128 0x3
    .byte   0x4
    .byte   0x5
    .string "int"
    .uleb128 0x2
    .long   .LASF1
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x7
    .long   0x50
    .uleb128 0x9
    .byte   0x3
    .quad   value2
    .uleb128 0x4
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x5
    .long   .LASF2
    .uleb128 0x2
    .long   .LASF3
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x3
    .byte   0xf
    .long   0x6d
    .uleb128 0x9
    .byte   0x3
    .quad   value3
    .uleb128 0x4
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x8
    .long   .LASF4
    .byte   0
    .section    .debug_abbrev,"",@progbits
.Ldebug_abbrev0:
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x11
    .byte   0x1
    .uleb128 0x25
    .uleb128 0xe
    .uleb128 0x13
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0xe
    .uleb128 0x1b
    .uleb128 0xe
    .uleb128 0x10
    .uleb128 0x17
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .uleb128 0x2
    .uleb128 0x34
    .byte   0
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0xe
    .uleb128 0x3a
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3b
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x39
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x49
    .uleb128 0x13
    .uleb128 0x3f
    .uleb128 0x19
    .uleb128 0x2
    .uleb128 0x18
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0x24
    .byte   0
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3e
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0x8
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .uleb128 0x4
    .uleb128 0x24
    .byte   0
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3e
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0xe
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .section    .debug_aranges,"",@progbits
    .long   0x1c
    .value  0x2
    .long   .Ldebug_info0
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0
    .value  0
    .value  0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .section    .debug_line,"",@progbits
.Ldebug_line0:
    .section    .debug_str,"MS",@progbits,1
.LASF1:
    .string "value2"
.LASF5:
    .string "GNU C17 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2) -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g"
.LASF0:
    .string "value1"
.LASF6:
    .string "short.c"
.LASF2:
    .string "short int"
.LASF3:
    .string "value3"
.LASF4:
    .string "unsigned char"
.LASF7:
    .string "/tmp/asm"
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

---

Comment: "Here is the .s output with -g:" -- I don't think that's useful, unless you explain what all these `.debug_info` bytes mean. Your answer would be better if you stopped after "o get p to work without debug information, ...do this" part.